# How to read and iterate JSON file contents?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

This is my `JSON` file.

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
}
```

I can read value of "webroot" as string and "exclude" as array using following snippet.

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("project.json");
Product pro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(file);
```

But I cannot read the value of dependencies. Its throwing exception as *"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'dependencies',..."*

My requirement is to read each value under dependency node and validate it. Then to add a new value and write it back to the json fie. Please help.

Edit:
My product class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Product
    {
        private string webroot;
        private string[] exclude;
        private string[] dependencies;
        public string WebRoot
        {
            get
            {
                return webroot;
            }
            set
            {
                webroot = value;
            }
        }

        public string[] Exclude
        {
            get
            {
                return exclude;
            }
            set
            {
                exclude = value;
            }
        }

        public string[] Dependencies
        {
            get
            {
                return dependencies;
            }
            set
            {
                dependencies = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its throwing exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: can you show your `Product` class?

Comment: What is the type of 'dependencies' field?

Comment: create a class with properties that are present in your json string.

Comment: Please refer my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dependencies` property is object with dynamic properties so you need some kind of dynamic object in your C# class.

The problem can be solved by using `Dictionary<string, string>` for `Dependencies` property. Here is an example:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Webroot { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public string[] Exclude { get; set; }
}

[ ... ]

static void Main()
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText("project.json");
    Product pro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);

    foreach (var dependency in pro.Dependencies)
    {
        // Here you can validate each property instead of printing it ...
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dependency.Key, dependency.Value);
    }

    pro.Dependencies.Add("NewProperty", "NewValue");

    var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pro, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(resultJson);
}
```

Comment: but `"dependencies": {` means it's an object not an array/list... Select the Json and in VS click Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as classes to see what it's supposed to be..

Comment: In C# it can not be an object because it has `dynamic` properties. How you'll define this class? What will happen if in the json there is one more property? This is why I don't use an array/list but `Dictionary<string, string>` ...

Comment: @Viktor Very thanks, its working. Using your code I can add new items to the file. What to do if I need to modify an existing items value? For example, I need to modify the version of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc to 5.0. And another case, how can I delete an existing key and value. Please help me.

Comment: You can use all methods from `Dictionary`. To remove some item -> `pro.Dependencies.Remove("Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc")`. To add/edit some item -> `pro.Dependencies["Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"] = "5.0"`.

Comment: @Viktor. Thanks. Please help me in this too. How to read this? `"frameworks": { "dnx451": { }, "dnxcore50": { } }`. If I use `private Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, string> _frameworks;`, its not working.

Comment: You can use `public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> Frameworks { get; set; }` or just `public Dictionary<string, object> Frameworks { get; set; }`. In the second example the object will be populated with `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`.

Answer (score 2):

To deserialize the file properly, your classes should look like this. Notice the `JsonProperty` attributes from `Json.NET`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Product
{
    public string webroot { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public Dependencies dependencies { get; set; }
    public string[] exclude { get; set; }
}

public class Dependencies
{
    [JsonProperty("EntityFramework.SqlServer")]
    public string EntityFrameworkSqlServer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("EntityFramework.Commands")]
    public string EntityFrameworkCommands { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc")]
    public string MicrosoftAspNetMvc { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can directly deserialize it using `Json.NET` like this

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\product.json");
var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(content);
```

In case, you just want to read some property/part of the json, you can use `Linq-to-Json` like this

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\product.json");

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(content);
string entityFrameworkSqlServer = (string)jObj["dependencies"]["EntityFramework.SqlServer"];
```