# Error in reading JSON object

Tags: c#, json

Am having the following Json file

```
 "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
},
```

and I have JSOn class in my project like below

```
public class ProjectJson
{
    public Dictionary<string,string > dependencies { get; set; }
}
```

And i am trying to read my json file by means of json class

```
ProjectJson jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectJson>(jsonContents);
```

But am getting the following error

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path
>   'dependencies.Microsoft.NETCore.Razor.Tools',.

I guess this is due to the structure of the node dependencies.Microsoft.NETCore.Razor.Tools .How to solve this issue?

Comment: What are you expecting/wanting? At the moment you are trying to put something into a `Dictionary<string,string>` but while you have an obvious key if the name your value is not a string. What do you want to be stored in the dictionary? Until we know that we can't know how to help you. Also what solutions are acceptable? Can you change the json to not have an object there? Can you change your `ProjectJson` object to have a different data structure? You need to be a bit clearer about what you want, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: Your json and your expected result does not tally. As above, it's unclear wwhat you expect it to do

Comment: I just want to read my json file as json object. so i have created a json class which will have same properties as like my json file. after that am deserilizing it . from my json file the following content can be fitted to a Dictionary property "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",". But the following cannot be fit in to dictionary "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
} . Casting my Json content to dictionary property is what the issue with my code i guess. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

edit: I misread the problem the first time. This is the revised answer.

You get an exception telling you it can't fit the `{ "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final", "type": "build" }` into a string as value for the `dependencies` dictionary.

The parsing should work if you change the type of `dependencies` to `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, JToken>`

original:
<strike>wrap the jsonContents with a "{" and "}" and then try again.</strike>

Comment: My Json content already wrap around "{}". Am unable to cast the dependencies to "Dictionary". that is the problem

Comment: I have cast this t dictionary with this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119297/how-to-read-and-iterate-json-file-contents

Comment: you could use the dynamic type which will fit the corresponding type of the data on runtime, with gettype you can also determine which type was chosen by the runtime and work accordingly with it

Comment: @user3610920 I don't understand your comment. How can you cast your dictionary when the exception is thrown while parsing?